# Convert regex into java regex

Tags: java, regex, string, validation, jenkins

string should ***not*** be longer than 26 alphanumeric characters
string should ***not*** begin with **www** OR **api** OR **admin**
string may contain hyphens

I have this regular expression that works:

```
^(?!www)(?!admin)(?!api)[a-zA-Z0-9.]{1,26}
```

Can you help me convert that regex into a java style string regex?

Comment: First, not every regex works with java, but anyway the easiest way is to use online tool for that like [advanced java](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: why isn't it working?

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code.

Comment: ^(www|api|admin)\w{1,26}$

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer by changing my regex to the following:

```
^(www|api|admin)\w{1,26}$
```

Comment: It does not even give the same result as the one you originally posted.